# Do I have a memory Leak, in my FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks

I am using FlowLayoutPanels. One user control has a FlowLayoutPanel, and when a button is clicked on that panel a Custom User Control is created and added to that flowlayout. Inside that Custom User Control I have a button `customButton2` and a handler `customButton2_Click`. And when `customButton2` clicked I want to remove the current UserControl from that FlowLayout. As you can see I tried to disposed them inside `customButton2_Click`. However when I add or remove a custom user control, memory usage increases. **As I said even if I delete something it increase the memory. I wrote a dispose and -= event handler for that button but nothing changes! Doesn't matter if I add or remove, memory usage increase no matter what. This is my main problem.** Could you please help me with that?

My main user control that has the FlowLayoutPanel object. Moreover this control adds the custom user controls to FlowLayout

```
    public partial class TodoList : UserControl
    {

        public TodoList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TodoListFlowLayout.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
            TodoListFlowLayout.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
            TodoListFlowLayout.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
            TodoListFlowLayout.AutoScroll = true;

        }


        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.TodoListFlowLayout.Controls.Count >= CommonVariables.TotalNumberOfTodoElement)
            {
                // Some Error message
                return;
            }

            TodoListPanel todoPanel = new TodoListPanel(TodoListFlowLayout);
            TodoListFlowLayout.Controls.Add(todoPanel);
            TodoListFlowLayout.Invalidate();
        }

}
```

My custom user control:

```
public partial class TodoListPanel : UserControl
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel;

        public TodoListPanel(System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayout)
        {
            // This control has 1 label 2 custom buttons and a one panel.

            InitializeComponent();
            this.label1.Click += todo_Element_Panel_Click; 
            this.customPanel1.Click += todo_Element_Panel_Click;
            flowLayoutPanel = flowLayout;

        }

        private void customButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.customPanel1.Click -= todo_Element_Panel_Click;
            this.customButton2.Click -= customButton2_Click;
            this.customButton1.Click -= customButton1_Click;
            this.label1.Click -= todo_Element_Panel_Click;

            foreach (TodoListPanel control in flowLayoutPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (this == control)
                    control.Dispose();
            }

            this.customPanel1.Dispose();
            this.customButton2.Dispose();
            this.customButton1.Dispose();
            this.label1.Dispose();
            this.Dispose();

            this.flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(this);
        }

        private void customButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Somethings happening
        }
        void todo_Element_Panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Somethings are happening here too
        }
    }
```

How can I handle this memory leak? Or Do I really have a memory leak? Please see my Diagnostic tool:

[image]

After yellow pointer shows up which indicates the Garbadge Collecter is running, I removed bunch of custom user controls, even if I removed them the memory usage increased!!

Comment: Why do you think the garbage collector needs to run and free memory while you watch? If you have enough RAM, it might *never* run. It doesn't need to. Is there a reason you think you have a memory leak?

Comment: I edited my question  @nvoigt does it answer your question? I might or not have a leak.

Comment: The GC run does not mean the GC will clean up. A GC run might well be the GC checking if you have RAM left and deciding that they won't bother. If you do that long enough (maybe programatically) do you at some point run out of memory?

Comment: @nvoigt ok but why deleting something increase memory usage?